# how to load a form into another form as child from an event of a third form?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Hopefully I can make this as clear as possible

I have 3 forms: `frmMain`, `frmLogin` and `frmDashboard`.

When the application opens `frmMain` opens as mdiParent with `frmLogin` as the mdiChild. After users enter correct credentials then `frmLogin` hides and `frmDashboard` opens as a child of `frmMain`.

The problem is I can't seem to get `frmMain` to be the parent of `frmDashboard` because it is being opened from `frmLogin`

The code on the `frmLogin` login button click is as follow:

```
if (account_exist == true)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Welcome back ");
   frmDashboard f = new frmDashboard();
   f.Show();
   this.Hide();
}
```

Can anyone help me with the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: `frmLogin.Parent = frmDashboard;` doesn't work (obviously replacing type names with variable names)?

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it is not possible to say for sure what is causing the problem. Please improve your question so that it includes a good code example. Also, please state _precisely_ what the code does and how that's different from what you want or expect.

Comment: In addition to what Hans says, MDI in general is being viewed more and more as "bad UI", and the support for MDI is fading (more like legacy at this point than anything else), I'd try to avoid MDI if you can.

Comment: I am working on a school assignment and MDI is what the teacher teaches and its what is on the syllabus. Thank @PeterDuniho and others for helping me improve this question instead of just down voting if there is anything else I should add let me know.

Comment: Try `f.Parent = this.Parent` just after creating the dashboard form.

Comment: I got the following message when I did that: "MDI child forms can be added only to MDI client. Parameter name: value."

Comment: @Kefash Sorry, it should be `f.MdiParent = this.MdiParent`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me with the best way to accomplish this?

The best and *only* correct way to do that is by [separating concerns](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

It is not the responsibility of your login form to do anything but login, and the main form should be notified of the completion of the login process. Once that happens, the main form should present whatever UI element(s) relevant to the post login phase.

Comment: how would I instruct the main form to do this?